# Postgresql 13 Change WAL segment size

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging

On my Ubuntu 20 server, I installed PostgreSQL 13 using the apt manager. I read some articles on performance tuning of PostgreSQL [1] and thought of increasing the WAL segment size (from default of 16MB). I see the following instruction, however, I don't know where to run this.

`initdb -D ./data --wal-segment=1024`

I guess the documentation refers to installing from PostgreSQL source code, which I don't intend to do. How do I go about change the WAL segment size?

[1] https://software.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/Open-Source-Database-Tuning-Guide-on-3rd-Generation-Intel-Xeon-Scalable-Processors.pdf

---

Following Daniel's answer, I did the following steps

```
$ pg_lsclusters
$ sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 13 main
$ sudo pg_createcluster 13 main -- --wal-segsize=256
$ sudo pg_ctlcluster 13 main start
```

You can verify the size of the WAL segments as

```
# du -hcs /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/pg_wal/*
```

Comment: Why do you think increasing the WAL segment size will increase performance (of whatever you want to increase performance of) in your particular case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu/Debian packages for Postgres have their own layer on top of `initdb` and `pg_ctl` to control multiple instances and the integration with systemd.

The command that may be used to create an instance with specific options in Debian/Ubuntu is:

```
pg_createcluster [options] version name [-- initdb options]
```

use `pg_lsclusters` to see the list of already existing clusters. Possibly you want to drop the existing default cluster named `main` using the default segment size that you don't want, in order to have one single Postgres instance with the desired wal segment size.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I did the following to drop and create a new cluster.
`pg_lsclusters
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 13 main
sudo pg_createcluster 13 main -- --wal-segsize=256
sudo pg_ctlcluster 13 main start`

Comment: Btw how do I verify the WAL segment size?

Comment: @tallharish: try `show wal_segment_size;` as a SQL command.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change the WAL segment size of an existing cluster, you can use `pg_resetwal`.

**Warning: for that, run `pg_resetwal` only on a cluster that has been shut down cleanly. Running `pg_resetwal` on a crashed cluster will cause potential data loss.**

The command would look somewhat like this:

```bash
/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_resetwal -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main --wal-segsize 64
```

You may need to increase `min_wal_size` if you increase the WAL segment size.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. Let me try this next time :). Meanwhile, how do I verify the WAL segment size?

Comment: `ls -l pg_wal` is a simple method.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz.  `du -hcs ./var/lib/postgresql/13/main/pg_wal/`

Comment: No, it is the size of the individual files, not the disk space occupied by the directory.

Comment: What happens to replication slots/servers if this is done to the primary? Does the secondary need to have the same wal-segsize as the primary?

Comment: @AlexiTheodore Yes. You will have to rebuild the standby.